# How to turn arbitrary number of strings into function arguments in python

Tags: python, function, arguments

I'm taking in data from a csv, and want to turn it into arguments for a python function.  For example, if the csv said

```
12, foo=20, bar=30
10, foo=17, bar=40, baz=12
```

I want to call my function twice, with `f(12, foo=20, bar=30)` and `f(10, foo=17, bar=40, baz=12)`.  I can't really modify the function (I'm actually using the requests library and turning this CSV into a series of requests).  Getting the strings out of the CSV is easy, but turning them into proper function calls doesn't seem to be.

For now what I basically have is this:

```
with open('request.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
       response = requests.get(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
```

But that doesn't work for arguments that should read "auth=X" or similar, nor for variable numbers of arguments.

Comment: what is your splitting criteria? Is it just the term without any `=`?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Andrej. Noah: It's a bit difficult to answer without knowing exactly what function are you passing these arguments to, what should be the arg type of the function argument etc.

Comment: Well, the csv split will happen on ",", and for some items  there will indeed be an "argument=X" syntax.  I'd also want to be able to pass a function in here, if a function would go in to the request (which can certainly happen).  For example, one argument might be "auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password')", and I'd want to pass all of that in as one argument, which shouldn't be a string in this case.

Comment: So to be specific:

If the line in the CSV was "www.foo.com/login", "auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password')"

I want to call 

requests.get("www.foo.com/login", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password'))

Answer (score 0):

```
line1 = '12, foo=20, bar=30'
line2 = '10, foo=17, bar=40, baz=12'

for line in [line1, line2]:
    args = line.split(',')
    # key named arguments (ignore first, bc it is unnamed)
    named_args = {k.strip(): v.strip() for k, v in (x.split('=') for x in args[1:])}
    # call your method
    method_to_call(args[0], **named_args)
```

Edit: I tested the code on my dev environment and updated it accourdingly. now it should work as expected.

Comment: I'm afraid this results in "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" on the "for" in 
named_args = { k,v for k, v in ( x.split('=') for x in args[1:])}

Comment: Ah, for those watching, the k,v should be in parenthesis.  I'm still figuring out if this works or not, but that's the issue at that point.

Trying to do this, I'm getting "line 107, in _transform_to_example
    context_expr.args[0].s,
AttributeError: 'Name' object has no attribute 's'"

Note sure what this means as "Name" is not found anywhere in my code, but this is breaking something.

Comment: This solution, once corrected for the missing () only yields "TypeError: get() argument after ** must be a mapping, not set"

Additionally, this means passing ('auth', "username, password") into the request, which isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(i, foo=0, bar=4):
    print(i, foo, bar)


row = '12, foo=20, bar=30'

args, kargs = [], {}
for arg in row.split(','):
    arg = arg.strip()
    if '=' in arg:
        key, value = arg.split('=')
        kargs[key.strip()] = value.strip()
    else:
        args.append(arg)

func(*args, **kargs)
```

Very dangerous solution:

```
def func(i, foo=0, bar=4):
    print(i, foo, bar)

row = '12, foo=20, bar=30'
eval('func(%s)' % row)

# Dangerous use:
row = '12, foo=20); sys.exit(0'
eval('func(%s)' % row)
```

Comment: That's incredibly dangerous on data coming from a CSV file or an Internet site that you basically know nothing about.  What if the row data is `); sys.exit(0` for example?

Comment: I had the feeling that it is a dangerous solution, without finding the reason why... so I edited the answer to include your example